# How do i provide new line between two tab using tabber class

Tags: javascript, css

[image: example for desired design]

Hii all, 
           am new to javascript and i don't know much about tabber class ,i would like to have a page where tabs are in two differnet line attached   system property page where tabs are in two different line .

```
           <div class="tabber">    
            <div class="tabbertab">    
            <h2>tab1</h2>    
            form stuff goes here...    
        </div>    
        <div class="tabbertab">    
            <h2>tab2</h2>    
            form stuff goes here    
        </div>    
        <div class="tabbertab ${tab_default}">    
            <h2>tab3</h2>    
            form stuff goes here    
            submit button here...    
        </div>
```

suppose these are two tabs which i would like to come into two different line...

Comment: I guess you mean this? http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber/ Anyway what you ask is against the very concept of tabs so I can only advice you to redesign the page without using tabs..

Comment: yaa @Shadow i would like to get these sort of tabs on page but like to seprate tabs into differnt line..is it possible??

Comment: @AMIT tabs means tabs next to each other, not one below the other. Can you post screenshot of the design you're after?

Comment: k am trying to insert it

Comment: here we have differnt tabs like general, computername and harware etc.here three tabs are in second line ..then kind of desgine am looking for

Comment: @AMIT ok I now understand and looks like the code you found is not supporting such feature. You'll have to look for brand new code/library allowing such thing..

Comment: EDIT: found something, will post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use code that support such feature, from quick look jQuery has several plugins:
http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/tabcontrol

For example [this one](http://vieln.e-supinfo.net/jquery/) have the "vertical" tabs you're after.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to insert this as separator:

```
<li style="display: block;"></li>
```

And create an empty div for corresponding tab "content".

Comment: this line i need to put in css file??

Comment: No, you need to put this into html

Comment: but am using tabber.js to create tabs then how i do that??